# Не получается создать новую запись в dict python

Tags: python, строки, словари

У меня имеется список строк, и я хочу создать словарь, где каждому слову из списка будет стоять в соответствии количество его вхождения в строку.

То есть вот такой код:

```
words = dict()
for str in lst:
    words[str] += 1
```

При попытке запустить код, на третьей строчке у меня выпадает ошибка с надписью:

```
KeyError: 'in'
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 6):

`words[str] += 1` равнозначно `words[str] =  words[str] + 1`, поэтому так как `words` изначально пустой, то `words['in']` вызовет `KeyError`. Чтобы исправить можно использовать `words = collections.defaultdict(int)`, который проинициализирует нулём (результат `int()`) при первом обращении. Или лучше

```
import collections

words = collections.Counter(lst)
```